# Collect errors in the last 24 hours from nginx log files

Tags: command-line, log, nginx, text-processing

I am trying to write a script to collect the last 24 hours logs from  nginx log files. My script is collecting all the logs from the log file and I need only last 24 hours errors.

*Script to collect last 24 Hours nginx `access.log` and `error.log`*

```
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-24 hours' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` '$4 > Date {print Date, $0}' /var/log/nginx/access.log > /data/production_logs/nginxaccess.log
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-24 hours' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` '$4 > Date {print Date, $0}' /var/log/nginx/error.log > /data/production_logs/nginxerror.log
```

*2nd Script:*

```
egrep 'Error|error|Exception|failed|Unhandled|err|Err' /data/production_logs/myapp.log > /data/production_logs/myapp_error.log
```

---

**Looking Script Example like below:**

```
egrep 'Error|error|Exception|failed|Unhandled|err|Err' /var/log/nginx/error.log > /var/log/nginx/last24hourlogs.log
```

To grep error exception at above from last 24 hours logs only and save it in as `last24hourlogs.log`

Log Format required:

```
2016/11/27 13:55:00 [error] 6822#0: *14569 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.182.171.4, server: myappserver
2016/12/03 12:51:26 [error] 6820#0: *19094 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 157.48.95.8, server:
```

**tail -f /home/example.com/.forever/bdapp.log**

```
2016/12/19 12:30:51 [error] 2147#0: *5647 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/myapp_email-templates/social-01.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.249.84.191, server: example.com, request: "GET /myapp_email-templates/social-01.png HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/12/19 12:30:51 [error] 2147#0: *5646 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/myapp_email-templates/social-02.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.249.84.128, server: example.com, request: "GET /myapp_email-templates/social-02.png HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: I don't have the file, what does a line exactly look like?

Comment: @Zanna Ah, great :)

Comment: @Zanna shouldn't be too difficult :)

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I have a perfectly working script, but I need to know the *exact* format of your lines, and also the script can be optimized if I knew if your file was sorted (no doubt) and how: latest messages first, or at the bottom of your file.

Comment: I need to grep or collect the last 24 hours error logs only from nginx log file to a custom file.

Comment: Please edit your question and give some example lines from the log files and tell us how it is sorted - earliest first or latest time first

Comment: And 2nd script added to send email and Its working fine.  _sendEmail -f "info@example.com" -t "info@example.com" -m "Alert Message " -u "Server Status" -s "smtp.infoxample.com:587" -xu "infoxample.com" -xp "dfdsfG86HKeB" -a /data/production_logs/nginx_error.log -a /data/production_logs/nginx_access.log_

Comment: Please provide the requested info ^ (sorted, how?, exact line format). Also it is not really clear to me, do you want *all* lines of past 24 hrs, or just the ones containing any of: `Error|error|Exception|failed|Unhandled|err|Err`. I need to teach a few hours, will finish the answer if noone does in between.

Comment: @Jacob I need _just the ones containing any of: Error|error|Exception|failed|Unhandled|err|Err._

Comment: @Jacob Please ignore the above message I need _all the line containing any of: Error|error|Exception|failed|Unhandled|err|Err._

Comment: Hi @RameshChand thanks! I only still need the exact format of the lines. Could you add a line from the file as an example? I need to be sure about the date format and the position of the date string + the sorting order.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob I have Updated the same above question section.

Comment: Hi @RameshChand, posted :)

Comment: @RameshChand , Could you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/860475/edit) your Q and post just a few lines of `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, because I see there is no _Date_ in 4th column as you have `awk` condition on it! then we can help better based on logs sample provided, thanks

Comment: @JacobVlijm, but there is no _date_ in 4th column, I think it's not original logs from `error.log`

Comment: Ramesh, I'd like to finish the answer, but need your information. Please could you answer my latest question below the answer. This is really communicating too slowly.

Comment: Jacob I have updated the 'log format required' which was grepped from the log file please see also Log Format required:

Comment: @RameshChand I have to give up. Again you provide another format. The question is unanswerable like you ask it.

Comment: @RameshChand in order to help you, we need to see the *execat* file you are trying to parse. Don't show screenshots (we need to be ab;e to copy it for testing) and don't add comments. Please [edit] your question and add i) an example of the file you want to process (if there are multiple date formats, we need to see *all* of them) and ii) the output you expect from that example input.

Answer (score 2):

### Reading a log file over x (last) hours, looking for specific lines

#### Important notes

- The answer below was written, based on the example OP provided, assuming the output example is an exact copy of how lines occur in the log file. This is essential for correct parsing out the date; if either the *position* or the  *format* of the time stamp is different, it will fail!
- Due to missing sorting information, the script could not be optimized for performance; all lines need to be checked, with the information we currently have.
- Unclear also is if the log file reports in UTC or local time, *and* in what time the report should be produced. "last 24 hrs" possibly needs to be corrected by the local time difference.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import calendar
import sys

#--- set conditions below 
matches = ['Error', 'error', 'Exception', 'failed', 'Unhandled', 'err', 'Err']
# ---

pattern = "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S"

source = sys.argv[1]
report = sys.argv[2]
last_hrs = sys.argv[3]

# shift =  time.timezone
shift = 0
now = time.time()

def convert_toepoch(pattern, stamp):
    """
    function to convert readable format (any) into epocherror
    """
    return int(time.mktime(time.strptime(stamp, pattern)))

with open(source) as infile:
    with open(report, "wt") as outfile:
        for l in infile:
            try:
                # parse out the time stamp, convert to epoch
                stamp = "".join(l.split()[:2])
                tstamp = convert_toepoch(pattern, stamp)
                # set the conditions the line has to meet
                if now - tstamp - shift <= int(last_hrs)*3600:
                    if any([s in l for s in matches]):
                        outfile.write(l)
            except (IndexError, ValueError):
                pass
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_log.py`
2. Run it with the sourcefile, the output file and the time as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_log.py <logfile> <ouput_file> 24
   ```

As mentioned, possibly the time (`24`) needs to be fixed by the local timezone. Please let me know.

#### What it does

- The script looks for lines with a time stamp, showing a time within the defined time period (x-hours back from now), comparing time from epoch. In case of a match, it looks if any of the conditional strings is in the file.
- If so, the line is written to the report

---

### EDIT

OP mentioned it didn't work. A test on both examples OP posted on request however, shows the script does the job perfectly:

#### Why does it work?

- Op's example- timestamp:

  ```
  2016/11/27 13:55:00
  ```

  is converted into the format:

  ```
  "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S"
  ```

  by the line:

  ```
  stamp = "".join(l.split()[:2])
  ```

  and subsequently converted to epoch:

  ```
  tstamp = convert_toepoch(pattern, stamp)
  ```
- The line:

  ```
  if now - tstamp - shift <= int(last_hrs)*3600:
  ```

  selects lines, stamped within `last_hrs` from now.
- The line:

  ```
  if any([s in l for s in matches]):
  ```

  subsequently looks if any of the strings:

  ```
  ['Error', 'error', 'Exception', 'failed', 'Unhandled', 'err', 'Err']
  ```

  occurs in the line.

As mentioned, I tested it thoroughly with the *exact* examples OP provided, and cannot come to another conclusion than that the script does its job.

Comment: There is no _ignore case_ in python? `matches = ['Error', 'error', 'Exception', 'failed', 'Unhandled', 'err', 'Err']`

Comment: @KasiyA Not that I know, but in can be shorter though, if we say: `if err in l.lower()`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @KasiyA ^...But that would possibly clash with other options, which might be case specific.

Comment: Thanks for the script let me check it and share the update soon.

Comment: @Jacob getting error: _python3 log.py /home/svn_manager/Do         cuments/bdapp.log  /home/svn_manager/Documents/bdapp_error.log
  File "log.py", line 38
    pass
       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
root@fileserver:/home/svn_manager/Documents# python3 log.py /home/svn_manager/Documents/bdapp.log  /home/svn_manager/Documents/bdapp_error.log
  File "log.py", line 38
    pass
_       ^

Comment: @RameshChand You must have copied/paste incorrectly. I just tried the posted code, and it does ***not*** have an indentation error. Please try again. Please note you that you should not change anything in indentation and/or spaces. They are essential in python.

Comment: I just try to execute it now its working but getting blank output from the log file even that file having error.

Comment: @RameshChand then please, please give me an *exact* example of the *input* lines, the lines in the log file. Obviously the input is different from the line you show as *output* in your question.

Comment: Please refer the sample log format: _Thu, 15 Dec 2016 00:35:50 GMT connect deprecated methodOverride: use method-override npm module instead at app.js:111:25_-------
_Dec 15 2016 12:35:50 AM+00:00 - error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0_

Comment: @RameshChand Aha, that is quite different :), no wonder it didn' t work. I will edit the script tonight.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! Look the another sample from nginx error log "upstream" : 

_2016/12/16 13:08:47 [error] 21313#0: *4645 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.196.26.252, server: example.com, request: "GET /example.com/apis/cities/10 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/apis/cities/10", host: "examle.com"_

Comment: Hi @RameshChand but that's a different format! As I explained in the answer, it is essential the script knows where to look for the date in what format.  Which of the two is the case in *your* log file?

Comment: Yes we have to export different error from the log file.

Comment: @RameshChand then please, please mention the specific and all formats the script has to take into account. I love to answer the question, but you are letting me beg for the relevant info. Not working. At all.

Comment: @Jacob I have updated the log format which was detected using tail command so please advise for such errors we need to export into a file using automatic shell script and notify to registered email id.

Comment: Hi @RameshChand I tested it inside out with the examples you provided. I cannot come to another conclusion that you make a mistake in either the set time, the time in the log files (too old?) or use incorrect arguments (although I don't see how you could. On the provided examples, the script simply works.

Comment: Hi @Jacob I have updated the screenshot after executing the grep command and its output for the current script we are looking where we can also add the word " error" " access denied" etc. refer the url here. http://www.screencast.com/t/KQJC7oYxk

Comment: @RameshChand Not sure what to do with the screenshot, but again, it shows another time format. I liked the question, but the information you provide is a mess, really. Unanswerable as it is.

Comment: @jacob can we discuss over Skype or other messenger you like?.

Comment: @RameshChand sure! Can you join me here? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50370/room-for-ramesh-jacob

Comment: @Jacob Please share the latest script if you have updated.

Comment: Hi @RameshChand , Please try the exsisting answer on "line1" from the chat session. It should work on example1. If it works, I'll add adaptions fro the other ones.

Comment: Hi @RameshChand just curious, but did you ever try ^ ?

Comment: Its works with for log files not for other log files

Comment: Could you please share a script with that script i can collect last 24 hours log to other output file ?

Comment: But for line1, there already is! As mentioned, could you run it on "line1"?